# 3D Planetary gravity

Tags: physics, javascript, grid, axis

so i am making a thing in javascript and i want to have planetary gravity in my "universe".

But when i use an equation to calculate the acceleration by gravity i get **one number**. That is how fast the object accelerates in the direction of the other object, but how do i **convert a speed in one direction to a speed in the X**, **Y** and **Z** axis?

Comment: Do you used Newton formula F=G*(M+m) / R^2 ? How do you calculated R ?

Comment: I used **Newton's law of universal gravity** (F=GmM/r^2) and converted the newtons you get from the equation to distance. See how i calculated the distance here: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/distance-2-points.html

Comment: you need some vector math : https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/vectors.html . The direction from A to B is B-A (vector difference) normalized. So (B-A)/r where r is distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gravity is additive. Calculate the gravity generated by planet A at point x. Then multiply by a unit vector pointing from x to A - that returns a vector, which gives the gravity a direction. Repeat for planet B, C, etc, then add the vectors.

Velocity is acceleration times time. Every frame, multiply the acceleration vector by the delta time, and add the result to the velocity vector. You can access x, y and z of the velocity vector directly.

A [vector](http://www.intmath.com/vectors/7-vectors-in-3d-space.php) simply stores the x, y, and z components independently. A [unit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) is a vector of length one - you make a unit vector by taking your vector and dividing each component by it's length, the length is `length = sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z)`. You add vectors by adding the components independently. You multiply a vector by a constant like gravity by multiplying it's components independently.

Comment: I know gravity is acceleration. But how do i convert the vector to x, y and z velocity?

Comment: well, i don't really know what a vector is, but i asume that it is a thing that stores the acceleration of x, y and z or something. I am coding in javascript so should i create an array with three numbers or what? The thing is, i have the speed and the direction, how do i convert it to x, y and z speed?

Comment: @DayDun Updated the answer

Comment: You're trying to do physics without having a minimal background in the math involved.  Your time is better spent reviewing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_mechanics before trying to implement a custom solution.